# 12/3 to disconnect box for mini split install?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, mini-split

I have an issue with installing a disconnect box for my 24k LG mini split condenser unit.  12/3 is coming from 20 amp double pole breaker to disconnect box with surge protection box(ICM517).  I understand the ground bar cannot be used with the neutral lines.  My question is how do I correctly connect the neutrals?

I have included pics on how I thought it would be right and also with neutrals disconnected.

hooked to bar ( incorrect?)
[image]

disconnected but nowhere to go?
[image]

Comment: Your mini-split condenser almost certainly **doesn't require a neutral**.  Could you update your post with the exact model?  My read of the ICM517 manual is you should connect one of your hot legs (e.g. the black one) through the surge suppressor before it goes on to the condenser.

Comment: Generally, the hots are switched (or run through the disconnect) while the neutrals are tied and run through the box to the load.

Comment: Yeah, do you even have a neutral coming from your minisplit?

Answer (score 5):

### Pull the neutrals out of the ground bar and join them with a wirenut

Routing neutral through an A/C disconnect is rather easy once you realize that you can splice inside it just the same as you would with an ordinary junction box.  So, all you have to do is remove the neutrals from the disconnect's bonded bar, nut them to each other with the appropriate sized wirenut, button the box back up, flip the breaker on, and call it a day!